# Merge xts objects with different frequences

Tags: r, merge, xts

Is it possible to merge xts objects with different time frequencies?

Data:

```
xts_daily <- structure(c(0.00268125, -0.00294375, -0.00575625, 0.00111875, 
            -0.0052875, -0.0206, 0.017525, 0.0053375, -0.0009125, 0.003775, 
            0.00393125, -0.00575625, -0.0027875, -0.00200625, -0.0040375, 
            -0.0065375, 0.0059625, 0.00299375, -0.00106875, 0.0047125, 0.001275, 
            -0.00294375, -0.00481875, 0.00080625, -0.01731875, -0.004975, 
            0.0165875, 0.002525, 0.00049375, 0.00424375, 0.00111875, -0.0077875, 
            0.001275, -0.00419375, -0.0165375, 0.0084625, 0.0065875, 0.0022125, 
            -0.0040375, 0.0069), class = c("xts", "zoo"), na.action = structure(1L, class = "omit", index = 883699200),index = structure(c(883958400, 
                                                                                                                                            884044800, 884131200, 884217600, 884304000, 884563200, 884649600, 
                                                                                                                                            884736000, 884822400, 884908800), tclass = "Date", tzone = "UTC"), .Dim = c(10L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("data.Open", "data.High", "data.Low", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      "data.Close")))


xts_minute <- structure(c(0.125, 0.0625, -0.125, 0.0625, 0, -0.1875, 0.09375, 
                          -0.03125, -0.09375, 0.0625, 0.125, 0.0625, -0.125, 0.09375, -0.03125, 
                          -0.1875, 0.09375, -0.03125, 0.03125, -0.0625, 0, 0.03125, 0.03125, 
                          0, 0, -0.125, -0.03125, 0.09375, -0.09375, 0.0625, 0.03125, 0.125, 
                          -0.09375, 0, 0, -0.125, -0.03125, 0.09375, 0, -0.03125), class = c("xts", 
                                                                                             "zoo"), na.action = structure(1L, class = "omit", index = 883729860), index = structure(c(883729920, 
                                                                                                                                                                                       883729980, 883730040, 883730100, 883730160, 883730220, 883730280, 
                                                                                                                                                                                       883730340, 883730400, 883730460), tzone = "America/Chicago", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(10L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Open", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "High", "Low", "Close")))
```

This doesn't work:

```
xts::merge.xts(xts_daily, xts_minute, join = 'left')
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
merge(xts_daily, xts_minute, all = T)
```

**UPDATE**

Following an update by the OP, one solution would be:

```
xts_daily <- as.data.frame(xts_daily)
xts_daily$Date <- row.names(xts_daily)
cln <- ncol(xts_daily) # 7
xts_daily <- xts_daily[, c(cln, 1:(cln-1))]
row.names(xts_daily) <- NULL

xts_minute <- as.data.frame(xts_minute)
xts_minute$Date <- row.names(xts_minute)
cln <- ncol(xts_minute) # 7
xts_minute <- xts_minute[, c(cln, 1:(cln-1))]
row.names(xts_minute) <- NULL

xts_sidebyside <- cbind(xts_minute, xts_daily)
```

Resulting in (`xts_sidebyside`):

```
                  Date     Open     High      Low    Close       Date   data.Open   data.High    data.Low  data.Close
1  1998-01-02 02:32:00  0.12500  0.12500  0.00000  0.03125 1998-01-05  0.00268125  0.00393125  0.00127500  0.00111875
2  1998-01-02 02:33:00  0.06250  0.06250  0.03125  0.12500 1998-01-06 -0.00294375 -0.00575625 -0.00294375 -0.00778750
3  1998-01-02 02:34:00 -0.12500 -0.12500  0.03125 -0.09375 1998-01-07 -0.00575625 -0.00278750 -0.00481875  0.00127500
4  1998-01-02 02:35:00  0.06250  0.09375  0.00000  0.00000 1998-01-08  0.00111875 -0.00200625  0.00080625 -0.00419375
5  1998-01-02 02:36:00  0.00000 -0.03125  0.00000  0.00000 1998-01-09 -0.00528750 -0.00403750 -0.01731875 -0.01653750
6  1998-01-02 02:37:00 -0.18750 -0.18750 -0.12500 -0.12500 1998-01-12 -0.02060000 -0.00653750 -0.00497500  0.00846250
7  1998-01-02 02:38:00  0.09375  0.09375 -0.03125 -0.03125 1998-01-13  0.01752500  0.00596250  0.01658750  0.00658750
8  1998-01-02 02:39:00 -0.03125 -0.03125  0.09375  0.09375 1998-01-14  0.00533750  0.00299375  0.00252500  0.00221250
9  1998-01-02 02:40:00 -0.09375  0.03125 -0.09375  0.00000 1998-01-15 -0.00091250 -0.00106875  0.00049375 -0.00403750
10 1998-01-02 02:41:00  0.06250 -0.06250  0.06250 -0.03125 1998-01-16  0.00377500  0.00471250  0.00424375  0.00690000
```

Comment: I would like to merge datetime with date, that is I want to keep datetime index. So date column should repeat itself for every time on specific date.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to provide an expected output? Thanks

Comment: Don't know how to construct output, but it's simple. I need to keep datetime index andd merge date to datetime. For example first row is 1998-01-02 02:32:00  0.12500  0.12500  0.00000  0.03125 from datetime and 1998-01-05  0.00268125  0.00393125  0.00127500  0.00111875 from date

Answer (score 1):

`merge(xts_daily, xts_minute, join = 'left')` works as expected. You're saying you want all the observations in `xts_daily`, and all the observations in `xts_minute` where `index(xts_minute) == index(xts_daily)`. There are no observations in both objects that have the same index, so all the columns of `xts_minute` are `NA`.

```r
merge(xts_daily, xts_minute, join = 'left')
##              data.Open   data.High    data.Low  data.Close Open High Low Close
## 1998-01-05  0.00268125  0.00393125  0.00127500  0.00111875   NA   NA  NA    NA
## 1998-01-06 -0.00294375 -0.00575625 -0.00294375 -0.00778750   NA   NA  NA    NA
## 1998-01-07 -0.00575625 -0.00278750 -0.00481875  0.00127500   NA   NA  NA    NA
## 1998-01-08  0.00111875 -0.00200625  0.00080625 -0.00419375   NA   NA  NA    NA
## 1998-01-09 -0.00528750 -0.00403750 -0.01731875 -0.01653750   NA   NA  NA    NA
## 1998-01-12 -0.02060000 -0.00653750 -0.00497500  0.00846250   NA   NA  NA    NA
## 1998-01-13  0.01752500  0.00596250  0.01658750  0.00658750   NA   NA  NA    NA
## 1998-01-14  0.00533750  0.00299375  0.00252500  0.00221250   NA   NA  NA    NA
## 1998-01-15 -0.00091250 -0.00106875  0.00049375 -0.00403750   NA   NA  NA    NA
## 1998-01-16  0.00377500  0.00471250  0.00424375  0.00690000   NA   NA  NA    NA
```

Based on your comment to another answer:

> I would like to merge datetime with date, that is I want to keep datetime index. So date column should repeat itself for every time on specific date.

It seems like you want to join the daily data with your datetime data, and repeat the daily data for every observation in the datetime data.

To demonstrate that, I need to create some datetime data because none of your datetime data exists in any of the days of your daily data.

```r
xts_days <- xts_daily[1:3,]
datetimes <- seq(as.POSIXct(start(xts_days)), as.POSIXct(end(xts_days)), by = "12 hours")
xts_intra <- xts(head(xts_minute, length(datetimes)), datetimes)
```

Then merge the two together, and use `fill = na.locf` to fill all the `NA` with the last observation carried forward.

```r
merge(xts_intra, xts_days, fill = na.locf)
##                        Open     High     Low    Close   data.Open   data.High
## 1998-01-04 18:00:00  0.1250  0.12500 0.00000  0.03125  0.00268125  0.00393125
## 1998-01-05 06:00:00  0.0625  0.06250 0.03125  0.12500  0.00268125  0.00393125
## 1998-01-05 18:00:00 -0.1250 -0.12500 0.03125 -0.09375 -0.00294375 -0.00575625
## 1998-01-06 06:00:00  0.0625  0.09375 0.00000  0.00000 -0.00294375 -0.00575625
## 1998-01-06 18:00:00  0.0000 -0.03125 0.00000  0.00000 -0.00575625 -0.00278750
##                        data.Low  data.Close
## 1998-01-04 18:00:00  0.00127500  0.00111875
## 1998-01-05 06:00:00  0.00127500  0.00111875
## 1998-01-05 18:00:00 -0.00294375 -0.00778750
## 1998-01-06 06:00:00 -0.00294375 -0.00778750
## 1998-01-06 18:00:00 -0.00481875  0.00127500
```

Answer (score -2):

I have found the solution. Variables names are different from the question post but it works on my variable names:

```
merged_diff <- merge(data.frame(date=lubridate::date(zoo::index(data_diff))),
                     data.frame(date = zoo::index(daily_diff), zoo::coredata(daily_diff)), all.x = TRUE, by='date')
```

Comment: I'm glad this does what you want, but it's not helpful to anyone else who visits your question later. When I try to run with the data in your question, I get a date column with all value equal to 1998-01-02, and then OHLC columns that are all NA.